# How to call pdflatex under TeX-PDF-mode?

Tags: auctex, tex

I am already in TeX-PDF-mode. When C-c C-c and type in pdflatex, it doesn't run. How can I run pdflatex in TeX-PDF-mode? Note: I don't change my emacs configuration file. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just type `latex` instead of `pdflatex` at the `C-c C-c` prompt. `TeX-PDF-mode` sets the TeX-engine to pdflatex automatically. The command you are entering at the prompt is only representative of what you want emacs to do i.e compile with `latex`, view the pdf file with `view` and so on. The actual commands the prompt can accept is given in the variable `TeX-command-list`.

The same works for any other engine say xetex. You set `TeX-engine` to xetex and call `latex` at the `C-c C-c` prompt.

Answer (score 1):

There's a command `TeX-PDF-mode` bound to `C-c C-t C-p` in my latex-mode, that's how I switch a buffer to using pdflatex instead of latex.